# Excel VBA counting horizontally

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range of cells starting in Column CA and going to CX what i need to do is count the number of cells in that range that have a value other than 0 just for one row at a time.

Comment: What about `=COUNTIF(CA1:CX1,"<>0")`?

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA for it? As @PeterAlbert mentioned you can do this via formulas?

Comment: You may also need to be careful on how you want blanks to be treated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. You will need to change the loop range based on your data

```
Sub CountValues()
    Dim lcell As Range
    Dim c_row As Long
    Dim values_counter As Long
    c_row = 0
    For Each lcell in Range("$CA$2","$CX$100")
        If lcell.row <> c_row then
           values_counter = 0
           c_row = lcell.row
        End If
        If lcell.value <> 0 Then
            values_counter = values_counter + 1
        End If
        If lcell.Column = Cells(1, "CX").Column Then
           'Do Something with values_counter here
        End If
    Next lcell

End Sub
```

Comment: Lcell is not populating with anything 
Sub CountValues()
    c_row = 0
    For Each lcell In Range("CA" & rowC, "CX" & rowC)
        If lcell.Row <> c_row Then
           values_counter = 0
           c_row = lcell.Row
        End If
        If lcell.Value <> 0 Then
            values_counter = values_counter + 1
        End If
          Next lcell
    values_counter = values_counter / 3

'End If
 End Sub

Comment: what do you mean `lcell` is not populating with anything `lcell` is a reference to the current cell in the loop `For Each` through a `Range` runs left - right then jumps down to the next row when it hits the right most column in the range.

Comment: It looks like lcell.value is always empty. in cell Ca2 I have a Date.